# Rendering differences between Firefox 3.0 and 3.5

Tags: html, css, firefox, standards, compatibility

I'm working on a large site and starting on browser compatibility next week. Just had a glance in some different browsers to have so idea of whats ahead of me and i noticed differences in FF3.5 vs FF3.

The site has been built in FF3.5/IE8. So I'm wondering if there are know issues between the two FF versions? A quick google search returned me nothing.

Regards,
Denis

Comment: So I finally fixed most of the issues and it turned out that alot of them were a simple issue created becasue the standards don't define what to do with a floated element that comes after an inline elment. The solution that worked for me was to also float the inline element. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: A knockon was that this helped with IE7!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are differences. Many bugs were fixed, many features implemented.

There's a list of new features in 3.5 on MDC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_3.5_for_developers#For_web_site_and_application_developers

...and you can get the list of all changes from bugzilla.mozilla.org, but that would be pointless, since probably only small part of them affect your app.

I think you should just try testing your app in 3.0.

Answer (score -1):

didn't saw any differences between FF 3.5 and 3.0

In some rare cases you can see differences between 2.0 & 3.5 for example you want to change appearance of upload file control, but for this example differences between different browser families are more evident.

In our company we use only latest version of FF for slicing work also because generally most of FF users (80%) have upgrade their browser in first month of version release

Comment: I must admit to having had the perception that most FF users upgrade but if you look at stats such as http://w3counter.com/globalstats.php and propably your own site metrics as I have you'll see it doesn't seem to be the case! Also I'm definitly seeing multiple differences across multiple pages between the two browsers but won't be looking further for a few days.